# Jolt Transformation Nested Arrays and Objects

Tags: json, jolt

I am attempting to create a jolt transformation for the below input:

```
{
  "admin": [
    {
      "heading": "header1",
      "fields": [
        {
          "description": "Name",
          "value": "John"
        },
        {
          "description": "Foo",
          "value": "Bar"
        }
      ],
      "id": "123456"
    },
    {
      "heading": "header2",
      "fields": [
        {
          "description": "Name",
          "value": "Jane"
        },
        {
          "description": "Foo",
          "value": "Bar"
        }
      ],
      "id": "789123"
    }
  ]
}
```

with the desired output of:

```
{
  "admin": 
    {
      "header1": 
        {
          "Name" : "John",
          "Foo": "Bar",
          "id": "123456"
        },

      "header2": 
        {
          "Name" : "Jane",
          "Foo": "Bar"
          "id": "789123"
        },
    }
}
```

I have just started understanding the basics of jolt transformations, but this seems a little complex with the nested structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec does what you want

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "id": "admin.@(1,heading).id",
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "value": "admin.@(3,heading).@(1,description)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This spec loops through the fields array and matches the description field to the keys looking up a level above with the value.